# jVectorMap: no mouseover and onclick possible

Tags: jvectormap

I need your help on jVectorMap installation. Please have a look at the project:

[HERE](http://www.yapeople.com/Hans+Spitzer/at)

Scroll down to the bottom left column and try to mouseover or click on any countries.

The code I initialize jVectorMap with is:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "worldmapdata.php",
    dataType: "json",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html)
    {
        var mapData;
        mapData = html;
        $('#world-map').html('');
        $('#world-map').vectorMap({
            map: 'world_mill_en',
            backgroundColor: '#a5bfdd',
            regionsSelectable: true,
            focusOn: {
                x: 0.4,
                y: 0.3,
                scale: 2.61464672130868
            },
            regionStyle: {
                initial: {
                    fill: 'white',
                    "fill-opacity": 1,
                    stroke: 'none',
                    "stroke-width": 0,
                    "stroke-opacity": 1
                },
                hover: {
                    "fill-opacity": 0.8
                },
                selected: {
                    fill: 'yellow'
                },
                selectedHover: {
                }
            },
            series: {
                regions: [{
                    values: mapData,
                    scale: ['#C8EEFF', '#0071A4'],
                    normalizeFunction: 'polynomial'
                }]
            },
            onRegionOver: function(e, el, code){
                el.html(el.html()+' (GDP - '+mapData[code]+')');
            }
        }).trigger('create');
    }
});
```

Would be great to get a hint to the right direction to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with your merged javascript or something is causing a conflict. I removed the js include from the HTML file (`http://www.yapeople.com/Hans+Spitzer/js/g=js_on`) and jVectorMap is working fine with mouse over and click events.

I even setup a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gD9Fd/) using your jVectorMap initialization code (without the conflicting js) and it is working as expected.

Try to build your merged JS with only jQuery and jVectorMap, and keep adding library/framework until it breaks. That will already give you an idea which code is causing the conflict.

Answer (score 0):

@Mike: Thank you for your answere, it helped me to solve the problem... it was the jquery.validate.js plugin. I don´t know why but for now I just disabled this plugin for the map to work.

Best regards,

Ingmar